# How to identify if the law of conservation of energy is violated in a nuclear reaction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics

I have encountered many textbook questions that ask for what laws of conservation is violated in a given nuclear reaction, and I can't seem to figure out how to identify if a nuclear reaction violates the law of conservation of energy.

Take for example,
\begin{align}
{e^+} & \to \  \mu^++\bar{\nu}_\mu+\bar{\nu}_e \\ 
p^\phantom{+} & \to\  n+e^++\nu_e
\end{align}

How can one deduce that these two reactions violate the conservation of energy?

Comment: wait. nothing violates the law of conservation of mass-energy. Even if mass is converted to energy E = mc^2.

Comment: It's not conservation of energy that is violated in the first reaction, but rather, a different conservation law.

Comment: @pentane Oh okay thank you, I think my textbook's answer printed the wrong answer for the first reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really tell: you can calculate the total rest-mass energy  on each side (i.e. $\sum_j m_j c^2$), but unless it's specifically noted, you can't make any assumptions about the kinetic energy on either side. In particular, if the rest-mass energy  of the decay products exceeds the rest-mass energy of the left-hand side, then you can give the reactants enough kinetic energy to overcome that barrier.

That said, there *is* an important observation in that such a reaction (where you have a single massive particle decaying to decay products which have more rest-mass energy than the initial particle) cannot happen *in vacuum*: this is because that decay can equally well be analyzed from the rest frame of the initial particle, and in that frame of reference the initial kinetic energy is zero.

However, if there is some interaction medium that can act as a catalyst (say, the air in a bubble chamber), then it does become possible to add enough kinetic energy to the reactants to overcome any given energy barrier. In that situation, the correct rest frame is the center-of-mass frame of the initial particle together with the catalyst, which is at rest in the laboratory frame, and in that moving frame there can be significant kinetic energy to use. The medium is considered a catalyst in that it does not take part in the reaction itself, but it does take part in the kinetic-energy exchanges (i.e. it will typically be required to end the reaction with a significant recoil kinetic energy in the lab frame, which will also need to be provided by the 'decaying' particle).

If you are answering these questions in the context of some class assignment, you need to check the text of the question carefully (and failing that, ask your instructor) to see which of those two contexts (decay in vacuum vs. in a medium) you need to assume. Given that they're asking about it, my starting assumption would be that the decays should be considered in vacuum (or else the question makes pretty much no sense at all) but if that wasn't clearly marked in the question, and the instructor wasn't available for inquiries, I would make sure to mark those reactions as "impossible in vacuum" rather than straight "impossible", for full correctness.

---

<sup>(And, as an aside: independently of energy conservation, one of the two reactions you've written down is impossible because it breaks *other* conservation laws.)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Conservation of energy is axiomatic (if we trust Emmy Noether). Kinetic and/or potential energy might not be constant or conserved. You must include mass-energy.

Conservation of linear momentum is axiomatic (if we trust Emmy Noether). The total momentum might change (i.e., the momentum isn't constant), but not without some external impulse adding another momentum vector to the system.

Conservation of angular momentum is axiomatic (if we trust Emmy Noether). The total angular momentum might change (i.e., the angular momentum isn't constant), but not without some external torque (a spin>0 particle entering or exiting the system) adding or removing an angular momentum vector in the system.

In all 3 of these situations you must pay careful attention to the reference frames: either don't change from before to after, or do a correct transformation.